# Runtime Error: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (62x2304 and 1568x3)

Tags: pytorch

I am un able to find error input 32*32 gray images:

```py
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(         
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1, # gray-scale images           
                out_channels=16,            
                kernel_size=5, # 5x5 convolutional kernel               
                stride=1,  #no. of pixels pass at a time                 
                padding=2, # to preserve size of input image                 
            ),                              
            nn.ReLU(),                      
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),    
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(         
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1, 2),     
            nn.ReLU(),                      
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),                
        )
        # fully connected layers
        self.out = nn.Linear(32*7*7, 3)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        # flatten the output of conv2 
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)    
        output = self.out(x)
        return output
cnn=CNN()
cnn
```

Comment: Check the shape of your `self.conv2` layers. I believe you forgot a `Flatten` in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linear layer expects input of size 32x7x7. Given that your `conv1` and `conv2` layers performs max pooling with stride=2, that means your network is configured for input size of 28x28 (MNIST usual input size) and not 32x32 as you expect.
Moreover, considering the values in your error message (64x2304) I assume you are working with batch_size=64, but your images are NOT 32x32, but rather 32x?? which is slightly larger than 32, resulting with a feature map of 32x8x9 after the pooling.

Comment: this code works fine with mnist 28x28x1 but i change dataset to celebA and took 3 classes with resize to mnist then it is producing error

Comment: @HijabSehar how do you resize? Are you sure you input images of size 3x28x28? From the error code you get it seems this is not the case.

Comment: '''
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Grayscale(), 
                                         transforms.ToTensor(),#to convert the images to the Tensor datatype.
                                         transforms.Resize(28), #28x28 frm 178x218
                                         #transforms.Normalize(0,0.5)
                                         ])

 train_set = datasets.ImageFolder('/content/drive/MyDrive/Celeb_data/train/mini',transform=transform)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

'''

Comment: @HijabSehar print the shapes of the images after the transforms. I think you'll be surprised by the values there. Then you can read the doc on `Resize` and figure out why the shapes are not as you expect.

Comment: thanks you are awesome.Resize resolved the problem. I changed to transforms.Resize(28,28)